# Setting number of unicorn workers from web using foreman vs from unicorn itself

Tags: ruby-on-rails, unicorn, foreman

I'm kind of stuck between setting the number of unicorn workers from foreman setting

```
web: bundle exec unicorn -p $PORT -c ./config/unicorn.rb
```

then while running `foreman start -c web=16`

or unicorn by just setting `worker_processes 16`

What if i set `foreman start -c web=8` while having `worker_process=2` does this mean it will just run total of 16

Is it just a preference or is there something that I don't understand? Can somebody please explain this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

foreman start -c web=16 will start 16 master unicorn processes each forking however many worker processes are set by default.

foreman start -c web=1 while setting worker_processes to 16 will start a single master unicorn process which will fork 16 worker processes.

The primary difference is who you are letting control the processes.  The unicorn master process is built around the idea of keeping track of it's forked processes and knowing when they have been hung, etc. for clean-up and restarting.  The foreman process would only know about the master unicorn process and not any of the processes forked by the master unicorn process.

The unicorn rack server is built to specifically to replace running multiple processes (for example 4 thin servers) and instead run a single master process and let it handle managing of the forked worker processes.  This allows a single process to be aware of all other processes serving the rack application.

In a nutshell - run a single unicorn process and add the # of workers in the config file.  Don't let foreman do it.